# Visual Studio Exceeded execution timeout, attempting to auto cancel

Tags: visual-studio

I am not sure what is causing this but while editing files within Visual Studio, I am periodically locking up with the following dialog showing.

[image]

Pressing cancel does nothing, after waiting for sometime I have to end VS via Task Manager.
I can't figure out why this comes up nor how to prevent it.

This is my VS configuration...

> Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 Version 17.3.0
> VisualStudio.17.Release/17.3.0+32804.467 Microsoft .NET Framework
> Version 4.8.04161
>
> Installed Version: Community
>
> Visual C++ 2022   00482-90000-00000-AA497 Microsoft Visual C++ 2022
>
> ADL Tools Service Provider   1.0 This package contains services used
> by Data Lake tools
>
> ASA Service Provider   1.0
>
> ASP.NET and Web Tools   17.3.375.53775 ASP.NET and Web Tools
>
> Azure App Service Tools v3.0.0   17.3.375.53775 Azure App Service
> Tools v3.0.0
>
> Azure Data Lake Tools for Visual Studio   2.6.5000.0 Microsoft Azure
> Data Lake Tools for Visual Studio
>
> Azure Functions and Web Jobs Tools   17.3.375.53775 Azure Functions
> and Web Jobs Tools
>
> Azure Stream Analytics Tools for Visual Studio   2.6.5000.0 Microsoft
> Azure Stream Analytics Tools for Visual Studio
>
> C# Tools   4.3.0-3.22401.3+41ae77386c335929113f61d6f51f2663d2780443 C#
> components used in the IDE. Depending on your project type and
> settings, a different version of the compiler may be used.
>
> Common Azure Tools   1.10 Provides common services for use by Azure
> Mobile Services and Microsoft Azure Tools.
>
> Extensibility Message Bus   1.2.6 (master@34d6af2) Provides common
> messaging-based MEF services for loosely coupled Visual Studio
> extension components communication and integration.
>
> GitHub Copilot   1.43.0.1 (v1.43.0.1@cb116db27) GitHub Copilot is an
> AI pair programmer that helps you write code faster and with less
> work.
>
> GitHub Copilot Agent   1.43.6621 (v1.43.0)
>
> Microsoft Azure Hive Query Language Service   2.6.5000.0 Language
> service for Hive query
>
> Microsoft Azure Stream Analytics Language Service   2.6.5000.0
> Language service for Azure Stream Analytics
>
> Microsoft Azure Tools for Visual Studio   2.9 Support for Azure Cloud
> Services projects
>
> Microsoft JVM Debugger   1.0 Provides support for connecting the
> Visual Studio debugger to JDWP compatible Java Virtual Machines
>
> Mono Debugging for Visual Studio   17.3.20 (3f4cb00) Support for
> debugging Mono processes with Visual Studio.
>
> Node.js Tools   1.5.40629.1 Commit
> Hash:3f5cc0329815af3ffb948f08857446d206a9af36 Adds support for
> developing and debugging Node.js apps in Visual Studio
>
> NuGet Package Manager   6.3.0 NuGet Package Manager in Visual Studio.
> For more information about NuGet, visit https://docs.nuget.org/
>
> Razor (ASP.NET Core)
> 17.0.0.2232702+e1d654e792aa2fe6646a6935bcca80ff0aff4387 Provides languages services for ASP.NET Core Razor.
>
> SQL Server Data Tools   17.0.62207.04100 Microsoft SQL Server Data
> Tools
>
> ToolWindowHostedEditor   1.0 Hosting json editor into a tool window
>
> TypeScript Tools   17.0.10701.2001 TypeScript Tools for Microsoft
> Visual Studio
>
> Visual Basic Tools
> 4.3.0-3.22401.3+41ae77386c335929113f61d6f51f2663d2780443 Visual Basic components used in the IDE. Depending on your project type and
> settings, a different version of the compiler may be used.
>
> Visual F# Tools
> 17.1.0-beta.22363.4+1b94f89d4d1f41f20f9be73c76f4b229d4e49078 Microsoft Visual F# Tools
>
> Visual Studio Inline Suggestions   2.2.2055.12395 Ghost text API for
> Visual Studio inline suggestions
>
> Visual Studio IntelliCode   2.2 AI-assisted development for Visual
> Studio.
>
> VisualStudio.DeviceLog   1.0 Information about my package
>
> VisualStudio.Mac   1.0 Mac Extension for Visual Studio
>
> VSPackage Extension   1.0 VSPackage Visual Studio Extension Detailed
> Info
>
> Xamarin   17.3.0.295 (d17-3@321c85a) Visual Studio extension to enable
> development for Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android.
>
> Xamarin Designer   17.3.0.208 (remotes/origin/d17-3@e4f67afef) Visual
> Studio extension to enable Xamarin Designer tools in Visual Studio.
>
> Xamarin.Android SDK   13.0.0.0 (d17-3/030cd63) Xamarin.Android
> Reference Assemblies and MSBuild support.
> Mono: dffa5ab
> Java.Interop: xamarin/java.interop/d17-3@7716ae53
> SQLite: xamarin/sqlite/3.38.5@df4deab
> Xamarin.Android Tools: xamarin/xamarin-android-tools/main@14076a6

Answer (score 3):

Same here, 7 times yesterday morning.
Copilot extension is also installed in my VS2022.
I've disabled copilot globally and no more incidents for now.